# non-trivial coefficients in an OLS regression

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, econometrics, regression-coefficients

I have a problem explaining how and why the coefficient on my regressions is changing signs.

I have a continuous outcome variable Y which is a linear combination of two continuous variables y1 and y2. Specifically:

```
Y= (we)*y1 + (1-we)*y2       where     0 < we < 1
```

I am interested in regressing an explanatory variable X on Y and its components y1 and y2 separately. The outcome variables Y, y1, and y2 are continuous and bounded between 1 and 10. X is a ratio and also strictly positive and takes values from 1 to 100

here is what is happening:

```
    regressing only X on y1 gives a negative and significant coefficient
    regressing only X on y2 gives a negative and significant coefficient
    regressing only X on Y gives a positive and significant coefficient
```

this is using the exact same sample across the 3 simple OLS regressions.. here is some additional information that I think might be causing this but I am not sure how exactly

```
    the correlation between y1 and y2 is 0.08
    the correlation between y1 and we is -0.05
    the correlation between y2 and (1-we) is 0.23
    the correlation between [(we)*y1] and [(1-we)*y2] is -0.38
```

I would like to know what situations could possibily cause the sign on the X coefficient to flip?